# Multi-tenant access to the same instance of enterprise apps

Tags: azure-active-directory

My customer is in process of migrating some of the their uses from the current tenant(tenant A) to new tenant(tenant B) and wants to know if the users from the tenant B can connect to the same SaaS-based apps & instances in tenant A using their tenant B environment credentials during and after the tenant migration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Multitenant can use their SAAS based app and Instances with any of their tenant credentials.

Software as a Service (SaaS) application - You can configure your application to accept sign-ins from any Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant. This configuration is called making your application multi-tenant. Users in any Azure AD tenant will be able to sign in to your application **after consenting** to use their account with your application.

Multi-tenant applications need to be provisioned in each directory where they will be used, **which requires user or administrator consent** to register them.

This consent process starts when an application has been registered in the directory and is given access to the Graph API or perhaps another web API. When a user or administrator from a different organization signs up to use the application, they are presented with a dialog that displays the permissions the application requires. The user or administrator can then consent to the application, which gives the application access to the stated data, and finally registers the application in their directory

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Multi tenant Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/app-types

**AAD Consent Framework** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework?toc=/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/toc.json&bc=/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/breadcrumb/toc.json